# Type Mismatch with Column number

Tags: excel, vba

I am not able to understand why excel says that my code returns a type mismatch error number 13 in the following lines of code:

```
Sub MySub()
Dim destinationWs As Worksheet
Dim DataColumn As Long, ShareColumn As Long, Number As Long
Set destinationWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

DataColumn = destinationWs.Columns(6)
ShareColumn = destinationWs.Columns(7)
Number = destinationWs.Columns(3)

(.....)
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: `DataColumn = 6`, `ShareColumn = 7`, `Number = 3`.

Comment: what do you expect to be in `DataColumn` after `DataColumn = destinationWs.Columns(6)`?  do you expect all the values from that column to be in an array?  Or do you expect `6` as in the column number?  If the prior, declare `DataColumn` as a variant.  If the later then just do what @BigBen stated.

Answer (score 2):

Worksheet.Columns property returns a **range object**. Your variables are being declared as `Long` so VBA is expecting a number, not a range object.

> Check [Worksheet.Columns property
> (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.columns)

**UPDATE:** Not sure what are you trying to do, but probably you want this:

```
Sub MySub()
Dim destinationWs As Worksheet
Dim DataColumn As Long, ShareColumn As Long, Number As Long
Set destinationWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

DataColumn = 6
ShareColumn = 7
Number = 3

'Then you can invoke those columns as

destinationWs.Columns (DataColumn)
destinationWs.Columns (ShareColumn)
destinationWs.Columns (Number)

(.....)
End Sub
```

Or maybe this:

```
Sub MySub()
Dim destinationWs As Worksheet
Dim DataColumn As Range, ShareColumn As Range, Number As Range
Set destinationWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Set DataColumn = destinationWs.Columns(6)
Set ShareColumn = destinationWs.Columns(7)
Set Number = destinationWs.Columns(3)

'Then you invoke them just with their variable name
DataColumn
ShareColumn
Number


(.....)
End Sub
```

Comment: @ScottCraner OMG!!! I totally forgot typing so fast!!! Thanks!!!